# What does this METAR remark mean? 'RMK RWY 7 ATIS G LL'

Tags: metar

I understand the long form:
"Remarks: runway 7 Automated Terminal Information Service (ATIS) G landline"

But what I don't understand is what runway 7 has to do with the ATIS information (this particular airport has one runway, RWY 7-25). What does the 'G' mean? What does the 'landline' mean?

Comment: Can you produce the entire ATIS

Comment: KLZU 211745Z 10006KT 10SM OVC018 13/03 A3005 RMK RWY 7 ATIS G LL

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have a suspicion that you're looking at KLZU's METAR. Basically, they're inputting their manually written METAR into the system, and when they send it out they're adding the Runway in Use(RWY 7) and ATIS code(ATIS G) to their METAR, which they're really not supposed to do. I suspect that LL is the person who recorded it's operating initials at the facility, also not supposed to be transmitted as a part of the METAR.

Comment: This is KLZU, that's pretty amazing you knew that. Thanks for the info, sounds like some manual mistakes on this one.